# Executing commands with incrementing filename with pause in between

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have files with numerical incrementing suffixes in filename

```
filename01
filename02
.
.
.
filename250
```

I want to be able to execute commands that can pause before the next cat command is executed

```
cat filename01
wait (1sec)
cat filename02
wait (1sec)
.
.
.
.
cat filename250
```

Please help. My last filename (filename250) can have a higher suffix. Not sure if I can do a for loop with a variable setting or if you share please a better recommendation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to sort those files numerically, best would be to use `zsh` instead of `bash` as it has a [`n`umericglobsort](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NUMERIC_005fGLOB_005fSORT) [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for that. Without it, your `filename250` for instance in a `filename*` glob expansion would sort between `filename25` and `filename26` as the default glob sorting order  is lexical.

```
for file in filename<1-250>(Nn); do
  cat < $file
  sleep 1
done
```

(also using the `N`ulllglob qualifier to avoid the error if there's no matching file).

Replace `<1-250>` with `<->` to match any number (sequences of 1 or more ASCII decimal digits), or `*` to match anything.

To cat a file every second instead of waiting one second between each `cat` (and take into account the time it takes to `cat` the file):

```
typeset -F SECONDS=0
n=0
for file in filename<1-250>(Nn); do
  cat < $file
  (( SECONDS >= ++n )) || sleep $(( n - SECONDS ))
done
```

(here assuming a `sleep` that can take floating point  numbers).

In `bash`, and on a recent GNU system, you can do something similar with:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }

readarray -td '' files <(
  print0 filename+([0123456789]) |
    LC_ALL=C sort -zV
)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  cat < "$file"
  sleep 1
done
```

Where we use GNU `sort`'s `V`ersion sort in the C locale to do something similar to  zsh's `n`umericglobsort glob qualifier.

(`bash` also has a ksh-style `$SECONDS` but unlike in ksh93 or zsh, it can't be `typeset` `F`loating point)

Comment: Hi Stephane, thanks for the feedback but my filename is fixed with leading 0, meaning the format is filename01.....filename99.....filename100. I cannot delete the 0 in the filename01 to filename1 as this is the format being injected in the dump directory. Will it still be okay for me to use ```<->```  or ```*``` will suffice?

Comment: @jovicue, yes, zsh's `<x-y>` matches any sequence of digits that represent numbers in that range, so `<1-3>` for instance will match on 2, 00002 or 000000000000002, and `<->` matches any sequence of any decimal digit including digit `0`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful! As for the sleep, incase executing ```cat filename01``` takes 10mins (including my filters), i just want for my system to briefly pause before running onto the next filename since it might affect my utilization, would you recommend a 1 sec sleep in between?

Comment: @jovicue, it sounds like only you can answer that question as you know what you need that delay for. You can also do something like `read -sk1 -t5` to sleep 5 seconds or let the user skip that delay by pressing a key.