# Running Commands on files sequentially

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script that will run a command on files in a directory sequentially with a pause for each command to wait to complete.  Here's an example.

```
cat >> text.txt && cat >> text2.txt
```

Above command works for both files as long as I manually type each file.  My personal project has 559 files, i.e., text1.txt...text559.txt.

My last resort is to pull up a list of the file names in the terminal and go to my text editor and just build the script for a one time run.  I would like to automate it if possible so any suggestions on how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: This is rather simular to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/739661...

Comment: Thanks.  Looked into that as well and that gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at a `for` loop. In `bash`, it would look something like:

```
for file in "${list_of_files[@]}"
do
  run_command "$file"
done
```

The `"${list_of_files[@]}"` can be an array that you set elsewhere, or you may replace this with a literal list of filenames, or it can be a filename globbing pattern such as `text*.txt`.

This loop will run `run_command` with a single parameter, the `$file` that you're working on in that loop iteration, and will wait for each `run_command` to complete before moving on to the next loop iteration.